# Hierarchy in SQL server 2005 with XML

Tags: xml, database, sql-server-2005, hierarchy

I wonder is there anyway to select hierarchy in SQL server 2005 and return xml format?
I have a database with a lot of data (about 2000 to 3000 records), and i am now using a function in SQL server 2005 to retrieve the data in hierarchy and return an XML but it seems not perfect because it's too slow when there is a lot of data

Here is my function

**Database**

```
ID      Name      Parent       Order
```

**Function**

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetXMLTree]
(
    @PARENT bigint
)
RETURNS XML
AS
    BEGIN
    RETURN /* value */
(SELECT [ID] AS "@ID",
        [Name] AS "@Name",
        [Parent] AS "@Parent",
        [Order] AS "@Order",
        dbo.GetXMLTree(Parent).query('/xml/item')
    FROM MyDatabaseTable
    WHERE [Parent]=@PARENT
    ORDER BY [Order]
    FOR XML PATH('item'),ROOT('xml'),TYPE)
    END
```

I would like to use XML in hierarchy because with me there's alot of thing to do with it :)
Any best solutions plzzzzz

Answer (score 8):

You can use a recursive CTE to build the hierarchy and loop over levels to build the XML.

```sql
-- Sample data
create table MyDatabaseTable(ID int,  Name varchar(10), Parent int, [Order] int)
insert into MyDatabaseTable values
(1, 'N1',     null, 1),
(2, 'N1_1',   1   , 1),
(3, 'N1_1_1', 2   , 1),
(4, 'N1_1_2', 2   , 2),
(5, 'N1_2',   1   , 2),
(6, 'N2',     null, 1),
(7, 'N2_1',   6   , 1)

-- set @Root to whatever node should be root
declare @Root int = 1

-- Worktable that holds temp xml data and level
declare @Tree table(ID int, Parent int, [Order] int, [Level] int, XMLCol xml)

-- Recursive cte that builds @tree
;with Tree as 
(
  select 
    M.ID,
    M.Parent,
    M.[Order],
    1 as [Level]
  from MyDatabaseTable as M
  where M.ID = @Root
  union all
  select 
    M.ID,
    M.Parent,
    M.[Order],
    Tree.[Level]+1 as [Level]
  from MyDatabaseTable as M
    inner join Tree
      on Tree.ID = M.Parent  
)
insert into @Tree(ID, Parent, [Order], [Level])
select *
from Tree


declare @Level int
select @Level = max([Level]) from @Tree

-- Loop for each level
while @Level > 0
begin

  update Tree set
    XMLCol = (select
                M.ID as '@ID',
                M.Name as '@Name',
                M.Parent as '@Parent',
                M.[Order] as '@Order',
                (select XMLCol as '*'
                 from @Tree as Tree2
                 where Tree2.Parent = M.ID
                 order by Tree2.[Order]
                 for xml path(''), type)
              from MyDatabaseTable as M
              where M.ID = Tree.ID
              order by M.[Order]
              for xml path('item'))
  from @Tree as Tree             
  where Tree.[Level] = @Level

  set @Level = @Level - 1
end

select XMLCol
from @Tree
where ID = @Root
```

Result

```xml
<item ID="1" Name="N1" Order="1">
  <item ID="2" Name="N1_1" Parent="1" Order="1">
    <item ID="3" Name="N1_1_1" Parent="2" Order="1" />
    <item ID="4" Name="N1_1_2" Parent="2" Order="2" />
  </item>
  <item ID="5" Name="N1_2" Parent="1" Order="2" />
</item>
```

Comment: you don't need a loop when using CTE

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy - If have no idea how to build hierarchical XML with a CTE. If you could provide an answer that shows how I would gladly give you a +1, learn from it and delete my answer. Until you do I will assume that you don't understand what the question is actually about.

Comment: @HieuNguyenTrung,  I managed to massively improve the performance of my script by creating a temporary table of just the records I needed in my hierarchy and then creating an index on a couple of the fields (id and parentId).  Initially my script took minutes to run and then with the temp table and indexes it was down to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

What benefit do you expect from using XML? I don't have a perfect solution for the case when you need XML by all means - but maybe you could also investigate alternatives??

With a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression), you could easily get your entire hierarchy in a single result set, and performance should be noticeably better than doing a recursive XML building function.

Check this CTE out:

```
;WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT
        ID, [Name], Parent, [Order], 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM
        dbo.YourDatabaseTable
    WHERE
        Parent IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        t.ID, t.[Name], t.Parent, t.[Order], Level + 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM
        dbo.YourDatabaseTable t
    INNER JOIN  
        Hierarchy h ON t.Parent = h.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY [Level], [Order]
```

This gives you a single result set, where all rows are returned, ordered by level (1 for the root level, increasing 1 for each down level) and their `[Order]` column.

Could that be an alternative for you? Does it perform better??

Comment: is there anyway to order? i can't order it like you did, it's not correct :(

Comment: @chrno love: specify an `ORDER BY` on your outer `SELECT` statement in such a way that it's "correct" for you...

Comment: i want to order it like descendants a XML

Answer (score 1):

I realise this answer is a bit late, but it might help some other unlucky person who is searching for answers to this problem. I have had similar performance problems using `hierarchyid` with XML:

It turned out for me that the simplest solution was actually just to call `ToString()` on the `hierarchyid` values before selecting as an XML column. In some cases this sped up my queries by a factor of ten!

Here's a snippet that exhibits the problem.

```sql
create table #X (id hierarchyid primary key, n int)

-- Generate 1000 random items
declare @n int = 1000
while @n > 0 begin

    declare @parentID hierarchyID = null, @leftID hierarchyID = null, @rightID hierarchyID = null
    select @parentID = id from #X order by newid()
    if @parentID is not null select @leftID = id from #X where id.GetAncestor(1) = @parentID order by newid()
    if @leftID is not null select @rightID = min(id) from #X where id.GetAncestor(1) = @parentID and id > @leftID

    if @parentID is null set @parentID = '/'

    declare @id hierarchyid = @parentID.GetDescendant(@leftID, @rightID)
    insert #X (id, n) values (@id, @n)

    set @n -= 1 
end

-- select as XML using ToString() manually
select id.ToString() id, n from #X for xml path ('item'), root ('items')

-- select as XML without ToString() - about 10 times slower with SQL Server 2012
select id, n from #X for xml path ('item'), root ('items')

drop table #X
```